# analysing the difference betweeen synchronize and lock

Tags: java, multithreading

I am a newbie to the world of Threads and I am going through threads to latest util package reentrant lock mechanism, I was going through the basis differences between synchronize mechanism and the newly added lock mechanism , as in the article these were the differences..

1. Another significant difference between ReentrantLock and synchronized keyword is fairness. synchronized keyword doesn't support fairness. Any thread can acquire lock once released, no preference can be specified, on the other hand you can make ReentrantLock fair by specifying fairness property, while creating instance of ReentrantLock. Fairness property provides lock to longest waiting thread, in case of contention.Please if you could provide a small program which proves this point sp that I can grasp more
2. main difference between synchronized and ReentrantLock is ability to trying for lock interruptibly, and with timeout. Thread doesn't need to block infinitely, which was the case with synchronized, Please if you could provide a small program which proves this point sp that I can grasp more
3. One more worth noting difference between ReentrantLock and synchronized keyword in Java is, ability to interrupt Thread while waiting for Lock. In case of synchronized keyword, a thread can be blocked waiting for lock, for an indefinite period of time and there was no way to control that. ReentrantLock provides a method called `lockInterruptibly()`, which can be used to interrupt thread when it is waiting for lock. Similarly `tryLock()` with timeout can be used to timeout if lock is not available in certain time period.Please if you could provide a small program which proves this point sp that I can grasp more

Guys could you please provide a small program which shows all these above three points

I have tried this program , please advise what changes need to be done in it to prove above 3 points..

```
public class ReentrantLockHowto {

    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private int count = 0;

     //Locking using Lock and ReentrantLock
     public int getCount() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " gets Count: " + count);
            return count++;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
     }

     //Implicit locking using synchronized keyword
     public int getCountTwo() {
            return count++;
     }



    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final ThreadTest counter = new ThreadTest();
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (counter.getCount() &lt; 6) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (counter.getCount() &lt; 6) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread-0 gets Count: 0
Thread-1 gets Count: 1
Thread-1 gets Count: 2
Thread-0 gets Count: 3
Thread-1 gets Count: 4
Thread-0 gets Count: 5
Thread-0 gets Count: 6
Thread-1 gets Count: 7
```

Comment: What would a program show that the above explanations and the javadoc don't already? Why don't you try to make such a program?

Comment: voting to close because this is too broad. go read Java Concurrency in Practice, it covers this topic and has example code.

Comment: These are concepts that are easier to understand explained like that rather than in a "simple" program. I would advise you to read more on Java concurrency so that you understand the core concepts. When you do, those explanations will become obvious.

Comment: The best way to learn is to write this code yourself! Go ahead. Get you a copy of Java Concurrency in Practice, read it and play with the example code there.

Comment: Where is your **synchronized** keyword?

Comment: @Ingo..I have missed it ..//Implicit locking using synchronized keyword
     public int getCountTwo() {
            return count++;
     }
..syncronize should be here

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  If you don't have an immediate need for this, I would just learn there are differences and examine them in more detail when you have a use case.

Comment: if there are mistakes in your question and you know them, please don't wait for someone else to correct them. Your question is interesting (otherwise you would not get upvotes), but you really should look after mistakes when they are pointed to you.